# SPA requests fails after about 40 minutes of inactivity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, single-page-application, azure-active-directory

Why my requests start to fail after about 40 minutes of inactivity?

I set up same authentication mechanism as in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapp-groupclaims (I am using Asp.Net MVC4 :

```
public partial class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = ConfigHelper.ClientId,
                Authority = ConfigHelper.Authority,
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = ConfigHelper.PostLogoutRedirectUri,
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                    {
                        ClientCredential credential = new ClientCredential(ConfigHelper.ClientId, ConfigHelper.AppKey);
                        string userObjectId = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(Globals.ObjectIdClaimType).Value;
                        AuthenticationContext authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ConfigHelper.Authority, new TokenDbCache(userObjectId));
                        AuthenticationResult result = await authContext.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                            context.Code, new Uri(HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path)), credential, ConfigHelper.GraphResourceId);
                    },

                    AuthenticationFailed = context =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error/ShowError?signIn=true&errorMessage=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

I am using angular2 SPA application and after period of inactivity, when application tries to send request, this request fails(
   In chrome tools I am seeing that API requests are redirected to authentication server(azure aad), but they are not processed by server properly and I see authentication server response on client side.
)

If I refresh the page everything is works fine.

I already disabled IIS recycling and set iddleTimout=0.

In web.config I disabled default authentication:

```
<authentication mode="None" />
<sessionState timeout="1440">
```

Comment: By default IIS removes a session after 20 minutes of inactivity

Comment: @M. A. Cordeiro, I already set `<sessionState timeout="1440">` to bigger than default value, is there any other place where I need to change default value?

Comment: I ran into a problem like that and I had to change my IIS configuration. I don't know why, but   my configurations didn't override IIS configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that if in `OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions UseTokenLifetime` set to true, cookie expiration time setting will be ignored. 
Also I found that I am using library where this setting set to true by default. This default behaviour has been changed, and now UseTokenLifetime set to false by default: https://github.com/aspnet/Security/commit/966fa6672ff3c5bd75703c325512778722ff46a2#diff-c130fbf3a8ec2c0c32beaf27fcf04ea9

So

```
 new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
                { UseTokenLifetime = false }
```

fixed my issue